# Nuxt 3 + TypeScript: property xxx does not exist on type Ref<xxx | null>

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have this repeating error message in Nuxt 3.9.3, on any variable I get from a useFetch.

For example. in this page:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <FilterActions
      :is-filtered="isFiltered"
      :search-result-text="data?.length"
    />
    <LotsViews
      :pending-lotes="pending"
      :lotes="data"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import FilterActions from '~/components/Common/FilterActions.vue'
import { LotsViews } from '~/components/Pages/Lots'

const isFiltered = ref(false)

const { data, pending } = await useFetch('/api/lot')
</script>
```

In FilterActions, isFiltered (which appears to be globalThis.Ref) throws no error, but :search-result-text="data?.length" ( does, and same goes for "pending" and "data" in LotsViews component.

"data" type appears as "Ref<SerializeObject[] | null>", and "pending" is "Ref". The error message for pending, for example, is

> "Type 'Ref' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)"

Apparently, variables which are "Ref" have some problem that those who are returned as "globalThis.Ref" doesn't have.

I didn't have this problem until I recently updated some dependencies (Nuxt included). I wonder how can I use data from "useFetch" now.

Actually, the app runs and builds without issues, but I have like 23 files with this error message, and I would like to get rid of it.

Comment: any update? Solution? Also. interested by the answer